# while executing make of i3-gaps, undefined reference to `g_utf8_make_valid' error

Tags: makefile, i3

After following all instructions from [Compiling and Installing](https://github.com/Airblader/i3/wiki/Compiling-&-Installing) page, I have successfully installed all the packages required. After performing `../configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --disable-sanitizers`, I get

```
build configured:

  i3 version:             4.15.0.1-323-gccb1947 (2018-09-28, branch "gaps-next")
  is release version:     no

  build manpages:         no
  build docs:             no
  enable debug flags:     yes
  code coverage:          no
  enabled sanitizers:     

To compile, run:

  cd /home/dharmin/i3-gaps/build && make -j8
```

Now, when I do `make` or `make -j8`, I get the following error

```
./libi3.a(libi3_a-string.o): In function `i3string_from_utf8_with_length':
/home/dharmin/i3-gaps/build/../../i3-gaps/libi3/string.c:59: undefined reference to `g_utf8_make_valid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On a quick google search, I found only one related [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/9hynio/having_a_hard_time_installing_i3gaps_on_debian/) link. But that did not help solve the problem.

My current i3 version
`Binary i3 version:  4.11 (2015-09-30, branch "4.11") © 2009 Michael Stapelberg and contributors`

Linux Distribution & Version: `Ubuntu 16.04`

Thank you in advance for helping :)

Comment: Reddit says "*`g_utf8_make_valid` requires libglib2.0-0 >= 2.51 which is not available in stretch or stretch-backports.*".

Comment: Yes, exactly. So, I checked if I have `libglib` or not, using `dpkg -l | grep libglib` and found `libglib2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

[I made a Reddit post mentioning this question.](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/9pzip8/i_managed_to_get_i3gaps_running_in_stretch_stable/e85h2as/) I was having the exact same problem and was tinkering away.

My final solution was to download version **4.13***, which does not make a reference to `g_utf8_make_valid`. If you have all the dependencies installed, it should compile fine.

* You are running 4.11. Installing 4.13 or something newer, depending on how new the libraries you can get are, might work, but I would try to install 4.11 in your case.